# Can power actually be sent into the ionosphere for transmission?

Tags: wireless

I always was amazed by a great man named Tesla. I have looked everywhere to see if I could get the truth of what he actually did but I just don't know what to believe. I don't what to trust, what to take as just a "false conspiracy" and how to get evidence.

Tesla brought the Radio, and the AC system and many other amazing electronics to the world, and his claims extended very far. I just don't know where to stop believing in his claims and where to know what was true or not.

One big controversy topic that I am particularly interested in is this. :

[image]

I have read a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932813860) , seen many [articles online](http://www.damninteresting.com/teslas-tower-of-power/), and watched [this](http://youtu.be/G_5_hJTJpRc?t=1h28m29s) all agreeing that this method can transmit power without power lines.

If any of this is even true, what methods would Tesla have been using to achieve this and why is his work never referred or attempted many years later?

Is it only because the electric companies are "money hogs" and don't want any of this?

Or is it because it is unsafe?

Or is it just totally some false claim that Tesla said and just built a tower for no purpose spite all of his experiments in Colorado springs?

Comment: This seems more like a physics or even a skeptics question. Tesla was a genius and a pioneer in electrical engineering, but this question has no definitive answer to be had on SE.EE.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier why not? This is about the practicality and other considerations of an electronics design, which is what this site is about.

Comment: @trav1s - The basic question regarding transmission of electricity through the ionosphere is based entirely in theoretical physics - not electrical design and implementation. There is a fine line between the two, but it is there. This isn't a question about electrical design, but about the principles of electricity, meaning physics. The rest of the question has little to do with anything beyond skepticism and "what ifs", hence, skeptics. Wireless power transmission is possible and is currently being implemented in various ways, but this question is way too open ended with no general direction.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier This question is on-topic because it relates to "the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces" (electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: *"Is it only because the electric companies are "money hogs" and don't want any of this?"* - No it's because your pension fund only invests in companies that avoid projects with negative ROI $$$.

Answer (score 13):

This is a complex question to answer, especially since Tesla borders on a deity for many.  Further, I am not an expert in Tesla so it is entirely possible that I am incorrect in some of the things that I post.

In life there are certain things that should raise red flags.  For example, a Dremel tool, duct tape, or a cordless sawz-all is an indicator that something has gone horribly wrong since nobody would/should use these items except as a last resort.  There are similar indicators for when you're in a discussion about religion, politics, weight loss, etc.  In technical circles, more than any other person, mentioning Tesla should raise many red flags.

It is not that Tesla was a crackpot, but that Tesla has been deified by so many other crackpots that it is often easier and quicker to assume that those who use his name are crackpots themselves.

Certainly Tesla's early life was filled with successes and brilliant innovation.  But later, his life took a remarkably more disappointing turn.  It is up for much debate, but there are those who believe that he was suffering from mental illness for roughly the second half of his life (1900-1943).  It was during those years that Tesla's productivity plummeted and his promotion of vaporware and outrageous claims skyrocketed.

Many of the ideas he put forth in the second half of his life have been latched on by the crackpot people, who assign almost magical properties to his as-yet undiscovered or undisclosed inventions.  Search on YouTube for "free energy" and many/most of the videos posted will invoke Tesla.

But his research and inventions during the first half of his life are mostly solid and demonstrate actual now-known scientific principles.  But here's the problem: Just because he showed something doesn't mean that it is practical, useful, or cost effective.  And just because people have not turned some of those inventions into modern appliances doesn't mean that there is a conspiracy to suppress them.  In many cases, they were just a scientific curiosity and doesn't actually represent something practical or economical.

Take wireless transmission of power over long distances as an example.  It's cool.  It makes for a flamboyant demonstration.  But it is nowhere near as practical or cost effective as running wires.  The efficiency losses of this is huge.  Sure, running wires for hundreds of miles is expensive, but wireless power transmission is only about 10-20% efficient if you're lucky.  Invest the money up front for the wires and you'll be saving money later on because you're not wasting as much power on a daily basis.

Even over the past 20-30 years there have been people trying to transmit power wirelessly.  Some people have proposed putting solar panel farms in space and beaming the power down to the ground.  Others have proposed using wireless power to send power from the ground to airplanes, rockets, etc.  These have all fallen flat because it just didn't make economical sense.

As for sending power into the ionosphere for transmission:  Yes, it's possible.  Basically you create radio waves of a specific frequency and send it at an angle into the ionosphere.  It will bounce off it, and come back down to the ground.  With this it is possible to send radio signals "over the horizon".  Early radio operators used this technique to communicate vast distances -- distances that would not have been possible otherwise.

Technically, if you send powerful enough radio waves it would be possible to power something on the receiving end.  Practically, however, it doesn't work that way.  With this method your efficiency would be abysmal.  Probably less than one millionth of the power would be recovered at the far end.  Further, the weather in the ionosphere will affect how well things bounce.  Early radio operators might go long stretches of time when communication between certain cities was impossible until the weather changed.

**Conclusion:**

It certainly seems that anything useful that Tesla did is already understood by scientists, and anything that is practical to be exploited has been exploited.  Anything that remains is not useful/practical/economical.

Further, anyone who claims otherwise should be treated with a healthy dose of skepticism.  Not all of them will be crackpots, but many of them will be (or at least lacking in scientific understanding).

Comment: +1 although your comment about duct tape is close to blasphemy

Comment: I'm curious as to the situations in which a Dremel tool is a red flag indicator. :)

Comment: @JYelton You broke/stripped a screw.  You bent a nail and can't pull it out.  You cut something just a hair too long.  Or your trying to adapt something for a purpose which it wasn't intended for.

Comment: @David What about grinding a rough aluminum edge on a DIY enclosure to a smooth finish, where larger tools cannot access?

Comment: I wouldn't take the comments about the Dremel and duct tape too seriously, man. The cordless Sawzall though, yeah. That's a red line. An international red line.

Comment: @dext0rb  Oh, I'm not taking anything seriously!  :)  As it is, I'm pleased that the tape/dremel is the only thing people take issue with (if only in jest).  I'm still waiting for someone to freak out because I suggested that Tesla could have a mental illness.  :)

Comment: haha I meant that for @JYelton, sorry David.

Comment: @Dextorb Gotcha, seriousness levels adjusted. David's still OK in my book. :)

Comment: I create all of those red flags on a daily basis. Obviously you've never prototyped anything in your garage or basement before.

Answer (score 3):

[This article from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wireless_System) should give enough background to see why such a system is possible. But the question of what is possible is not particularly interesting. Just because something is possible doesn't mean it is logical. Clearly, one cannot go through life doing every possible action one is confronted with. One must make careful consideration as to the practicality and ethicality of any choice. In that regard, here are a couple practical and ethical questions that should be asked and answered for such a world wireless system:

1. Will such a system negatively effect the flora and fauna of earth?
2. Is the system, including all infrastructure, more economical than alternatives?
3. Is the system safe?

While these questions cannot be answered with certainty as such a system has never been built and tested, here are some educated guesses:

1. Almost certainly. Radio waves already disrupt many species such as migratory birds in negative ways, and such a system could only exacerbate the problem.
2. Almost certainly not. Most of the population of the world is in urban areas. A wireless system would definitely be less efficient means of distribution, and there is just not a big need for it. Part of this is a historical issue. Humanity has built its infrastructure around wired power, so usurping the establishment is no easy task.
3. One would have to run extensive simulations or calculations on how this would interact with the atmosphere before having reasonable confidence that there are no unintended consequences.

**While it is possible, there is currently too much stacked against it for it to be implemented.**